# Schedule and cancel scheduled push notifications on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I would not be posting this question if scheduled push notifications could be cancelled programmatically on Parse..

On the `afterSave` method of one of my classes, if the item is new, I have to select `n` users of a specific role and send a push notification to these users. If none of these users *pick* the new item after ~10 minutes, I have to send a push notification to other `n` users, and so on, without repeating users. If a user picks the item, I have to stop sending push notifications.

What I'd like to do is to send the first batch of notifications when the new item is created and then schedule the next batches. If a user picks the new item I have to **cancel** the push notifications that were scheduled.

I have read about using an [iron.io](http://www.iron.io) [worker](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/api/#queue_a_task) for this (some examples [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-a-cloud-code-function-to-be-invoked-periodically)) but I'd like to know if anybody knows any other interesting solutions to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative design is to not worry about scheduling and unscheduling, but instead run something recurring, unconditionally, on a short interval that figures out who -- if anybody -- should get a push now.  This might be doable as a parse scheduled job, or you could still use a 3rd party tool.

Comment: @danh Hmm that sounds like an interesting idea.. If I create a recurring job that runs every ~10 minutes I could just check if there are any push notifications to be sent. They won't be sent exactly after 10 minutes on the first time but that is not gonna be a problem...